# Standards-conforming ways for static links in local HTML table of contents to display local docs in browser with no server

Tags: html, security, browser

I want to take a local tree (folders within folders) of PDFs and create a static HTML table of contents in the root folder. You double-click the "index.html" or open it with the browser's File > Open..., and it shows you static links (& descriptions, etc.) pointing at the PDFs. Click a link to view that PDF in the browser.

No server (remote or localhost), no Javascript fetching (static links), no JQuery, no HTTP(S), presumably no CORS, no workarounds with flags or extensions, just a local HTML file opening local PDFs in a standard, reliable way with a standard, unmodified browser.

For security reasons, there are lots of issues with local files, so I'm asking, What are the standard, reliable, cross-browser links and targets that will work? So, for example, link opens on the same page or in a new tab or in an iframe? Which will work and which won't? Or "File://" or absolute "/.../..." or relative URLs? Or PDFs pointed at must be in the same folder or a descendant folder or can be in any (local) folder?

I'm not asking for a single approach that seems to work. I'm asking which options are valid? Which of these various ways of opening a local file from a local HTML file are considered standard and reliable by browser makers?

Answer (score 0):

Decide what your root location is
lets say I call mine `c:\Data\mysampledata\pdf` with subfolders.

So I start the browser at that OS instantly auto generated tabular `index.html`

[image]

If I enter a html link it opens a pdf or a subfolder with links to pdf

[image]

So on Windows at least its already programed for you no need to duplicate the wheel with a log

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -app="C:\Data\pdf"`

That command can be run or shortcut or goto via right click or any of the other do OS native methods

It does not matter which browser here is a Mozilla variant that's equally trusted to browse the local system by auto generating the links as index.html

[image]

Now you save and have your "static" index.html in an OS acceptable structure, and you can edit the descriptions plus add thumbnails by injection or find and replace

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this view of a browser auto-displaying directory listings, but my question is about options when designing a nice table of contents page. If, for example, opening in a new tab was uncontroversial but local TOC opening local file in iFrame was sometimes blocked or browser makers were debating blocking it (a still-open question), the latter would not be a usable design option. Likewise, type of URL. What can I count on as reliable design options with standard browsers?